# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-0,274697\n'

Tags: python

I'm now programming ecg signal with python and i have this error i dont know how i can solve it.

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-0,274697\n'

[image]

Comment: Please post your code **as text**, using a formatted block, into the question. Thanks.

Comment: in consol i got this   
  File "C:/Users/Imrane/Desktop/WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5/settings/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 121, in rateKommentar
    return float(datei.readline().replace('#',''))

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-0,274697\n'

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please type your code out instead of having it in a picture. Also, on which line is the error occurring. (There are multiple conversions to float in the code you have posted)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so you are trying to convert a string with a `,` to a floating point number.

In Python, you can't have a comma in your number, only a `.` is supported. To convert it, you can use these lines

```
 datei= open(dateiname,'r')
 dateistr = datei.readline().replace(',','.') #replacing comma with .
 dateistr = dateistr.replace('#','') # replacing # with blank
 dateistr = dateistr.strip('\n') #remove the new line character at the end
 return float(dateistr)
```

Comment: Oops. Good catch. My mistake

Comment: you can just use `strip()` instead of `strip('\n')` - it stripes all whitespaces automatically